# List of numbers of intersections

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists of list

```
#   x x    x    <-- intersection
c=[[1,2], [2,3]]
b=[[1,2], [2,0]]
```

As a result, I need for each pair of inner lists the number of equal elements on equal position. For the above example, the intended result will be `[2, 1]`

I currently have:

```
def intersect (l1,l2,count):
    count=0
    for i in l1:
        if i in(l2): count=count+1.0
    return count

c=[[1,2], [2,3]]
b=[[1,2], [2,0]]
count1=[]
count=0
for i in c:
    for j in b:
        count1.append(intersect(i,j,0))
```

Comment: Your original indentation was off the charts. Please check if the collective editing wisdom converged on what you expected.

Comment: (It should be *then* and `intersect()`.) The code presented seems to not separate `def`ining `intersect()` from using it. Are you allowed to use the python library?

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is that you are not happy with?

Comment: What's the expected result if `c = [[1,1,]]` and `b = [[1]]`? `[1]`? `[2]`? By the way, you should try to explain your problem more clearly. There are already 3 "unclear what you're asking" close votes on your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are they of equal row size? In that case we could use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

c = [[1,2], [2,3]]
b = [[1,2], [2,0]]
output = (np.array(c) == np.array(b)).sum(axis=1).tolist()
```

[2,1]

If we got different lengths we could probably zip and use this:

```
output = [(np.array(i[0]) == np.array(i[1])).sum() for i in list(zip(c,b))]
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution just zips your lists which will result in ignoring any excess elements in the inner or outer list as the example data should make clear

```
def intersection(b, c):
    count = []
    for l1, l2 in zip(b, c):
        n_same = sum([1 for x1, x2 in zip(l1, l2) if x1 == x2])
        count.append(n_same)        
    return count

# or as a one-liner
intersection = lambda b, c: [sum([1 for x1, x2 in zip(l1, l2) if x1 == x2]) for l1, l2 in zip(b, c)]

#     x  x    x                          x     x       x   <-- intersection found
c = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 0], [6, 7, 8], [8, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
b = [[1, 2], [2, 0], [1, 2], [7, 6, 6], [8, 8, 8], [2, 2], [3, 4]]

print intersection(b, c)

>>> [2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1]
```